# I'm trying to create a tree from a folder in Google Drive, but I don't get any output

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps-script

I'm trying to modify from this code to list files and folders in a specific folder, rather than all folders:

```
/* Change the FOLDER NAME to generate tree for any specify folder */

function generateFolderTree() {

  try {

    // If you want a tree of any sub folder
    var parent = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('TitaniumBackup').next();

    // If you want to search from the top (root) folder
    //var parentFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();

    getChildFolders(parent);

  } catch (e) {

    Logger.log(e.toString());

  }

}


function getChildFolders(parent) {

  var childFolders = parent.getFolders();

  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {

    var childFolder = childFolders.next();

    Logger.log("Folder Name: " + childFolder.getName());
    Logger.log("Folder URL:  " + childFolder.getUrl());

    var files = childFolder.getFiles();

    while (files.hasNext()) {

      // Print list of files inside the folder
      Logger.log(files.next().getName());

    }

    // Recursive call for any sub-folders
    getChildFolders(childFolder);

  }

}
```

But when I run it, and after giving the authorization, I don't see any html file inside my drive.  Why?

I'm trying to modify from this code:
https://ctrlq.org/code/19923-google-drive-files-list

Answer (score 0):

The Script doesn't create an HTML file. The results are written on the Google Apps Script log, using the [Basic Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#basic_logging). Basically once your script ran, click View > Logs.

Comment: No logs found. Use Logger API to add logs to your project.

I got this message but the logs are empty